# "localhost refused to connect" - Jupyter Lab/notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab

I have using Jupyter notebook regularly. Today when I shut down my system after using it, and turned it again, I cannot reach the app anymore. It shows `localhost refused to connect`. Everything seems fine(?) in the terminal - these messages were displayed earlier as well.

```
[I 2021-11-14 15:03:15.880 ServerApp] jupyterlab | extension was successfully linked.
[W 2021-11-14 15:03:15.883 NotebookApp] 'extra_static_paths' was found in both NotebookApp and ServerApp. This is likely a recent change. This config will only be set in NotebookApp. Please check if you should also config these traits in ServerApp for your purpose.
[W 2021-11-14 15:03:15.883 NotebookApp] 'kernel_manager_class' has moved from NotebookApp to ServerApp. This config will be passed to ServerApp. Be sure to update your config before our next release.
[W 2021-11-14 15:03:15.883 NotebookApp] 'use_redirect_file' has moved from NotebookApp to ServerApp. This config will be passed to ServerApp. Be sure to update your config before our next release.
[W 2021-11-14 15:03:15.883 NotebookApp] 'use_redirect_file' has moved from NotebookApp to ServerApp. This config will be passed to ServerApp. Be sure to update your config before our next release.
[W 2021-11-14 15:03:15.887 ServerApp] The 'kernel_manager_class' trait of a ServerApp instance expected a subclass of 'jupyter_server.services.kernels.kernelmanager.MappingKernelManager', not the AsyncMappingKernelManager AsyncMappingKernelManager.
[I 2021-11-14 15:03:15.894 ServerApp] retrolab | extension was successfully linked.
[I 2021-11-14 15:03:15.909 LabApp] JupyterLab extension loaded from /home/amzon-ex/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jupyterlab
[I 2021-11-14 15:03:15.909 LabApp] JupyterLab application directory is /home/amzon-ex/.local/share/jupyter/lab
[I 2021-11-14 15:03:15.911 ServerApp] jupyterlab | extension was successfully loaded.
[I 2021-11-14 15:03:16.009 ServerApp] nbclassic | extension was successfully loaded.
[I 2021-11-14 15:03:16.010 ServerApp] retrolab | extension was successfully loaded.
[I 2021-11-14 15:03:16.011 ServerApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: /mnt/c/Amzon/Lab/pylabs
[I 2021-11-14 15:03:16.011 ServerApp] Jupyter Server 1.11.1 is running at:
[I 2021-11-14 15:03:16.011 ServerApp] http://localhost:8888/lab?token=5d46ff341e4b13023e47b6675ac0a7e45b4a51fcbe1c3eed
[I 2021-11-14 15:03:16.011 ServerApp]  or http://127.0.0.1:8888/lab?token=5d46ff341e4b13023e47b6675ac0a7e45b4a51fcbe1c3eed
[I 2021-11-14 15:03:16.011 ServerApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
[C 2021-11-14 15:03:16.061 ServerApp]

    To access the server, open this file in a browser:
        file:///home/amzon-ex/.local/share/jupyter/runtime/jpserver-568-open.html
    Or copy and paste one of these URLs:
        http://localhost:8888/lab?token=5d46ff341e4b13023e47b6675ac0a7e45b4a51fcbe1c3eed
     or http://127.0.0.1:8888/lab?token=5d46ff341e4b13023e47b6675ac0a7e45b4a51fcbe1c3eed
```

I don't doing anything other than installing the `jupyter_contrib_nbextensions` for my jupyter notebook - which I configured and successfully used for an entire session. Any ideas on why this could be happening?
By default JNB opens on port 8888 - and so it has for so long - I don't see a reason why it might be blocked.

Comment: can you `ping localhost`?

Comment: @JoshFriedlander Yes, I can.

Comment: You said you use Jupyter regularly.  Do you use Amazon AWS regularly or did you just recently use one of the AWS services ?   Because you have evidence of having used Amazon's AWS in the code you provided.   Any ideas just come to mind?

Comment: @Gray No I don't, actually!

Comment: maybe a problem with the browser?

Comment: @Axeltherabbit At that point of time, it seemed like a restart of the computer fixed it, and I have no idea why.

Comment: I have been using Jupyter Notebook/Lab for 5+ years now and suddenly today I got the same problem. Did you figure out what caused this issue? I tried uninstalling and installing Anaconda, and restarting the computer but they did not help.