# Why does Jupyter Notebook/Lab fails to connect on localhost despite server launch? Anaconda on Windows 11

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, localhost, jupyter-lab

I have been using Jupyter Notebook/Lab for 5+ years and never had an issue with it launching. Today, I tried launching Jupyter Lab from command prompt but even though Jupyter Server ran as always and localhost tab popped up in my browser, I saw the following error in my browser:

> This site can’t be reached 
> localhost refused to connect.

**Details:**

```
(base) C:\>jupyter lab
[I 2024-02-26 10:58:00.260 ServerApp] jupyter_server_fileid | extension was successfully linked.
[I 2024-02-26 10:58:00.260 ServerApp] jupyter_server_ydoc | extension was successfully linked.
[I 2024-02-26 10:58:00.260 ServerApp] jupyterlab | extension was successfully linked.
[I 2024-02-26 10:58:00.260 ServerApp] nbclassic | extension was successfully linked.
[I 2024-02-26 10:58:00.512 ServerApp] notebook_shim | extension was successfully linked.
[I 2024-02-26 10:58:00.512 ServerApp] panel.io.jupyter_server_extension | extension was successfully linked.
[I 2024-02-26 10:58:00.527 ServerApp] notebook_shim | extension was successfully loaded.
[I 2024-02-26 10:58:00.534 FileIdExtension] Configured File ID manager: ArbitraryFileIdManager
[I 2024-02-26 10:58:00.534 FileIdExtension] ArbitraryFileIdManager : Configured root dir: C:
[I 2024-02-26 10:58:00.534 FileIdExtension] ArbitraryFileIdManager : Configured database path: C:\Users\amirhhm\AppData\Roaming\jupyter\file_id_manager.db
[I 2024-02-26 10:58:00.534 FileIdExtension] ArbitraryFileIdManager : Successfully connected to database file.
[I 2024-02-26 10:58:00.534 FileIdExtension] ArbitraryFileIdManager : Creating File ID tables and indices with journal_mode = DELETE
[I 2024-02-26 10:58:00.534 ServerApp] jupyter_server_fileid | extension was successfully loaded.
[I 2024-02-26 10:58:00.534 ServerApp] jupyter_server_ydoc | extension was successfully loaded.
[I 2024-02-26 10:58:00.534 LabApp] JupyterLab extension loaded from C:\Users\amirhhm\AppData\Local\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\jupyterlab
[I 2024-02-26 10:58:00.534 LabApp] JupyterLab application directory is C:\Users\amirhhm\AppData\Local\anaconda3\share\jupyter\lab
[I 2024-02-26 10:58:00.534 ServerApp] jupyterlab | extension was successfully loaded.
[I 2024-02-26 10:58:00.534 ServerApp] nbclassic | extension was successfully loaded.
[I 2024-02-26 10:58:00.534 ServerApp] panel.io.jupyter_server_extension | extension was successfully loaded.
[I 2024-02-26 10:58:00.543 ServerApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: C:\
[I 2024-02-26 10:58:00.543 ServerApp] Jupyter Server 1.23.4 is running at:
[I 2024-02-26 10:58:00.543 ServerApp] http://localhost:8888/lab?token=bf71e43526056e848f03a66e9ec52e31d997b9b2f41940af
[I 2024-02-26 10:58:00.543 ServerApp]  or http://127.0.0.1:8888/lab?token=bf71e43526056e848f03a66e9ec52e31d997b9b2f41940af
[I 2024-02-26 10:58:00.543 ServerApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
[C 2024-02-26 10:58:00.575 ServerApp]

    To access the server, open this file in a browser:
        file:///C:/Users/amirhhm/AppData/Roaming/jupyter/runtime/jpserver-3300-open.html
    Or copy and paste one of these URLs:
        http://localhost:8888/lab?token=bf71e43526056e848f03a66e9ec52e31d997b9b2f41940af
     or http://127.0.0.1:8888/lab?token=bf71e43526056e848f03a66e9ec52e31d997b9b2f41940af

(base) C:\>
```

**What I have done:**

It seems like this issue was brought up in here in this question (["localhost refused to connect" - Jupyter Lab/notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69961851/localhost-refused-to-connect-jupyter-lab-notebook)) but there is no answer and the author of the question said in the comments that "a restart of the computer fixed it." I have restarted the computer and it did not resolve the issue.

Here is a list of other things I have tried that have not worked:

- Updated Anaconda, Jupyter Notebook, and Jupyter Lab
- Uninstalled and installed Anaconda
- Tried opening the localhost link in another browser
- Tried launching Jupyter in another conda environment

**Question:**

Given that I see "**(base) C:>**" in command prompt, I think the issue must be with Anaconda since it seems as if the server is immediately stopped after launching. What are your thoughts on this issue?

I am on Windows 11, using Anaconda version 2.5.0, Jupyter Lab version 3.6.3, and Jupyter Notebook version 6.5.4.

Comment: Any recollection of things that you have done (installed packages, updated stuff etc) prior to this behaviour showing up?

Comment: I did not install or update any packages but I remember my PC auto updated when booting up. Could that be the source of the problem?